# Should taglibs be declared in included JSP files?

Tags: java, jsp, taglib, jspinclude

I have several JSP files that are included into other JSP pages.  Some of these use taglibs declared in the pages that include them.

Should these taglibs be declared in the included files as well?  If so, do they need a different prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to define them again - you can use them in the included files as well.

Comment: That's what I thought, but Eclipse likes showing errors in functions from taglibs defined in the outer files.

Comment: Simply put it doesn't know which, if any, JSP files include the fragment.